# Custom progress bar in android given in image

Tags: android

[image: Custom image progress dialog for android]

How to design the progress dialog given in the image? Is there any third party libraries for this type of progress dialog? I trying to find the libraries for this design from the last 3 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this library to achieve step progressbar

https://github.com/baoyachi/StepView

Code from repo page :

```
<com.baoyachi.stepview.HorizontalStepView
            android:id="@+id/step_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            /> 


HorizontalStepView setpview5 = (HorizontalStepView) mView.findViewById(R.id.step_view5);
        List<StepBean> stepsBeanList = new ArrayList<>();
        StepBean stepBean0 = new StepBean("接单",1);
        StepBean stepBean1 = new StepBean("打包",1);
        StepBean stepBean2 = new StepBean("出发",1);
        StepBean stepBean3 = new StepBean("送单",0);
        StepBean stepBean4 = new StepBean("完成",-1);
        stepsBeanList.add(stepBean0);
        stepsBeanList.add(stepBean1);
        stepsBeanList.add(stepBean2);
        stepsBeanList.add(stepBean3);
        stepsBeanList.add(stepBean4);


        setpview5
                .setStepViewTexts(stepsBeanList)//总步骤
                .setTextSize(12)//set textSize
                .setStepsViewIndicatorCompletedLineColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.white))//设置StepsViewIndicator完成线的颜色
                .setStepsViewIndicatorUnCompletedLineColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.uncompleted_text_color))//设置StepsViewIndicator未完成线的颜色
                .setStepViewComplectedTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), android.R.color.white))//设置StepsView text完成线的颜色
                .setStepViewUnComplectedTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.uncompleted_text_color))//设置StepsView text未完成线的颜色
                .setStepsViewIndicatorCompleteIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.complted))//设置StepsViewIndicator CompleteIcon
                .setStepsViewIndicatorDefaultIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.default_icon))//设置StepsViewIndicator DefaultIcon
                .setStepsViewIndicatorAttentionIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.attention));//设置StepsViewIndicator AttentionIcon
```